# Jade doesn't render checkboxes text?

Tags: html, checkbox, pug

im trying to put chekcboxes input on my html file using compiled jade, it renders the actual checkboxes but not the text i.e.

```
          p.confirm
            input(type="checkbox", name="agree") 
              | I agree to the Terms & Conditions of this Company <br />
            input(type="checkbox", name="subscribe") 
              | Tick to recieve future communication from Company
```

I tried the jade docs but nothing happens, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input tags do not have children.

```
p.confirm
    input(type="checkbox", name="agree")
    I agree to the Terms & Conditions of this Company
    br
    input(type="checkbox", name="subscribe")
    Tick to recieve future communication from Company
```

Comment: i tried this it deosnt work, it was mentioned in the issues on github  https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/445

Comment: The thing is, that an `input` can not have child elements.

Answer (score 23):

I'm not sure how the accepted answer can work, as Jade will interpret the text as tags if not escaped.

Both of these will work instead:

```
p.confirm
  label
    input(type="checkbox", name="agree")
    | I agree to the Terms & Conditions of this Company
  br
  label
    input(type="checkbox", name="subscribe")
    = " Tick to recieve future communication from Company"
```

label is needed to make text clickable.